# Having power restored to pole barn

Tags: conduit

We just moved into a home 2 weeks ago that has a 25'X 55' pole barn.  Previously (pre 2017), the wiring from the meter (located ~75' away from the barn's panel) was cut.  The conduit is buried, the wiring and boxes/fixtures are all there and in good shape according to the electrical company.  I'm wondering why the buried conduit would be ~16" from the wall and the panel was strung off the framing using just a few pieces of 2x4.  **What would be my best course to correct this offset so the power company will come restore power?**  I do plan to have a slab poured in the spring.

Should I simply disconnect the wiring, remove the panel (frame in and attach it to the structure), dig down to the elbow so I can cut it back and relocate the line in?  Seems simple but looking for advice so I wont have to do it again before or AFTER the slab is poured.

[image: ~16" offset from wall]

Comment: Can you post the full-resolution photo of the first photo (to reduce file size, save it full-resolution at JPEG quality 3) ... or a better shot of your panel there?  The thing looks ancient and decrepit (the white handles, notably), and may not comply with modern codes. Also does your meter pan out at the pole have a main breaker located there? And is your state on NEC 2020, do you know?

Comment: Also, do you have the deadfront cover for that panel? Or was it mislaid or stolen?

Comment: Is adding some Unistrut or the likes to support the panel independently of the pole barn an option?

Answer (score 1):

The power company shouldn't care about how the panel is mounted provided it is secure and passed inspection. Your plan to cut at the elbow and move everything to the wall is sound but keep in mind that you'll have to remove the wires in the conduits to reroute the conduits and then the old wires will not reach so you'll need to pull new wire or add a junction box below the panel. It's anyone's guess why it was put in that way, maybe some underground utilities or footers. You'll need a cover for that panel and if the panel is old and rusted, you might want to replace it.. The wiring from the meter to the panel is your responsibility and from the meter to the power company facilities is theirs in most cases. Explain what wires were cut please.

Comment: If this is the first disconnect past the meter, the power company has a say in it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica    Every state I've worked in that falls under the inspection, not the utility.  The utility might want initial access to it to turn it off before energizing the meter but I've never heard of them refusing to connect after an inspection unless there was a safety issue they observed after an old inspection in which case they'd request another inspection..

Answer (score 1):

### Working space

First, there is good reason to "pop out" a panel like that: **Working Space**. Each panel requires a 30" wide x 36" deep x 6'6" tall space in front of it, *which must be kept clear At All Times*.  When a panel is pinned against a wall, it inevitably gets junk stored in front of it - somebody has to be the Working Space nazi and scold everyone not to put stuff there.  We don't like nazis, so it's better to "design the problem away" by placing the panel in an aisleway or threshold.

Now if that wall is intended to get shelving, say about 2 feet deep, the offset would place the panel right in the aisleway for that shelving.  Perfect!

### Stability

I don't like the looks of that wall.  I see a pole barn with regular framing and bracing, except for a gap in framing in the area of this panel: Just a very long horizontal span of what looks like a few 2x4s. They have no flex resistance and neither does the sheathing.  Such a wall will tend to go "wibble-wobble" in the wind, arcing a few inches back and forth.  That motion is transferring to the panel and its conduits, which is not allowed. In a severe storm that entire wall could even be blown out, dragging the electrical panel with it!

All that to say that wall appears unsuitable for the placement of a service panel.

I think if I were your inspector, I would want to see the panel disconnected from the wall entirely, and supported by posts on either side with Unistrut spanning them, or something like that.

I gather power reaches the house via this panel?  I have other concerns about the age/vintage of your panel there, and whether the setup conforms to modern Code, but I'd need more information to assess it.